# Drupal admin login failed

Tags: apache, drupal-7, ubuntu-14.04

I have Drupal 7 website, the login page "/user" opens normally, when i try to login with no feedback not loging in and no error message, whatever values i enter

- I tried to reset the password using the built in script "password-hash.sh" and copied the hashed to the db, not working
- tried to make the $cookie_domain = 'mydomain.com'; @ sites/default/settings.php, not woking
- tried to clear the sessions table and also tried to "`repair table sessions`" and clear cache table, not working
- mod_rewrite, is already enabled, checked that too,
- Database connection is ok, website is working normally

I would really appreciate for any more ideas or any log guidance to follow,

Comment: have you cleared your flood table. if this didnt fix your problem use drush uli to generate one time login link.

Comment: Flood table worked :), thanks alot, Would you make it as a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drupal after 5 invalid login attempts the user is blocked. In this case you must clear your flood table ( Only truncate it never drop it ). This will fix the access restrictions after 5 invalid attempts to any user in drupal.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot that fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you've just added new site to apache's configuration be sure to run:

```
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

Comment: no it wasn't new site, thanks for @Viswanath, for the flood table idea